# Front of Drupal Admin Menu Bar is Suddenly Showing Unwanted Items

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-navigation

On the admin menu bar it suddenly started showing `import files`, `import files` again, and `manage display`. Also, when I would try to create a new content type, the front of the admin menu bar would then have that content type's name shown on the bar. I'm using Drupal 7 and am getting this same problem with all two of my browsers.

I don't know what else to add other than I just noticed that I'm not getting log messages that appear to be the reason to the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, read the [ask] page and update your question.

Comment: how is it now Jeroen?

Comment: Try to remove the new content type is order to repair your environment. Did you folow the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/nodes-content-types-and-fields/create-a-custom-content-type)?

Comment: After removing the content type, the `import files` and `manage display` options are still there. And they aren't listed under my "Management" menu configurations.